# How can I configure wordpress to run auto updates from admin when my server is running php7

Tags: php, wordpress, libssh

It seems that the `php ssh2 / libssh2` is not available in php7 so easily. I am trying to install it and just cant find any information online.

If I run this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2–1-dev libssh2–1
```

I get these errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package libssh2–1-dev
E: Unable to locate package libssh2–1
```

It seems the way is to download the pecl package and make install manually however, I cant get passed the first bit of installing libssh2??

Any help appreciated.

I tried this tutorial https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/solution-how-install-ssh2-php7-extension-sanjog-kumar-dash

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy the code. Type it manually. Looks like the dash in the command `sudo apt-get install libssh2–1-dev libssh2–1` is not the right one.